# 301 Redirect a URL to the home page using htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to 301 redirect from:`https://www.domain.co.uk/?404;http://www.domain.co.uk:80/sn-down-to-earth.html` to `https://www.domain.co.uk/`

In my `.htaccess` file I have the following:

`Redirect 301 "/?404;http://www.domain.co.uk:80/sn-down-to-earth.html" https://www.domain.co.uk/`

I have a few hundred redirects in the `.htaccess` file already which all work fine. I think its to do with the `?` or `;` in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think its to do with the `?` or `;` in the URL?

Yes, it is to do with the `?`, which delimits the query string in the URL.

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string (everything after the first `?`). To match the query string you need to use mod_rewrite with a *condition* that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. In your example, the URL-path is *empty*.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =404;http://www.domain.co.uk:80/sn-down-to-earth.html
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) makes this a lexicographical (exact match) string comparison (as opposed to a regex).

The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag removes the query string from the redirect response. This requires Apache 2.4. The query string is otherwise passed through by default.